# How to close a console application within the specified number of hours?

Tags: c#, console

I was tasked to append a timer within my working console app to let it close automatically after some time without requiring a user input.
My application has functions that delete certain data in the database based on some conditions and exits everytime the user inputs 'exit'.
Now the requirement is to automatically stop the process even if the deleting of items is not yet done given that the time set to close the application is provided, say 2 hours.

Can someone help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved this problem by having an app.config file where there is a value for key="Stoptime".
I then added a condition that checks the current time against the set end time. Following is an example solution (for those having the same problem):

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string stoptime = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Stoptime"];
        DateTime timeEnd = Convert.ToDateTime(stoptime);

        today = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine(today);

        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            id.Add(i.ToString());
        }

        foreach(string item in id)
        {
            today = DateTime.Now;

            if (timeEnd.CompareTo(today) >= 0)
            {
                Console.CursorLeft = 0;
                Console.Write(item + " " + today);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("break.");
                break;
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create a `System.Timers.Timer` with an interval of `TimeSpan.FromHours(2)` and call `Environment.Exit()` in its `Elapsed` handler.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that killing the program is a good idea since you are manipulating data in a database but I think would be the simplest way to do it.

```
using Timer = System.Threading.Timer;

class Program
{
    private static readonly Timer  _timer = 
        new Timer(o => Environment.Exit(0), null, 5000, Timeout.Infinite);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of Timeout.infinite in this case if we are also specifying due time. What is the difference in due time and period here?

Answer (score 0):

1) create a timer
2) set interval and the elapsed event handler
3) enable the timer for run

when timer triggers in the method hooked to the event just exit the application

Answer (score 0):

If you are deleting data from database  then stopping it Abruptly could be catastrophic. So you can implement somthing like this.

- Perform the time consuming operation in a [BackGroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-en/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)
- Implement a Timer as explained in other examples.
- Then when the Tick/Interval Event is raised Request the BackgroundWorker to Cancel the Task.
- In your Do Work code Listen for this Cancel request and stop the deletion process safely(Either the Do Deletion or Don't Perform the it At all)
- Then Use Environment.Exit() to exit out of the program.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Shekhar, I will look into implementing this. However, the deleting part is not done manually using a query. It is done by a method from a K2 library (i assume it to be atomic given that it is done within a loop), I just determined which processes to delete.